# SpreadJs set border on a merged range

Tags: javascript, spreadjs

I  would like to set a border on a merged range using spreadJs spreadsheet library, however I cannot get this to work.

```
const lineStyle = GC.Spread.Sheets.LineStyle;
const lineBorder = GC.Spread.Sheets.LineBorder;
const borderColor = 'rgb(255,0,0)';

var option = {
    all: true
};

sheet
    .getRange(1, 1, 3, 2)
    .setBorder(new lineBorder(borderColor, lineStyle.thin), option);
```

Instead it is just doing the top left square, has anyone got any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Which version of spreadJS are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 12.0.7

Comment: How are you creating the span?
What framework are you working in?
It seems to be working on my end